# How to find the minimum and maximum values of the BST given below?

Tags: recursion, binary-search-tree, sml

Below is the code I currently have. Not sure if it is even right, but the datatype line MUST remain the same. I am trying to create a getMin and getMax function. Below will be the requirements for it.

```
datatype tree = leaf | node of int * tree * tree;

fun isEmpty leaf = if leaf=nil then true else false;

fun inorder leaf = nil
  | inorder (node(key,left,right)) = inorder left @ [key] @ inorder right;

fun preorder leaf = nil
  | preorder (node(key,left,right)) = preorder left @ preorder right @ [key];

fun postorder leaf = nil
  | postorder (node(key,left,right)) = [key] @ preorder right @ preorder left;

(* Inputs a BST. Returns the smallest value in the tree. If the tree is empty, the function should return NONE. *)
    getMin : tree -> int option

(* Inputs a BST. Returns the largest value in the tree. If the tree is empty, the function should return NONE. *)
    getMax : tree -> int option
```

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Go all the way to the left for the minimum and all the way to the right for the maximum.

Comment: the problem I am having is formatting the code.

Comment: especially since it wants INT Option instead of just an int

Comment: Can't help you with that as I have no idea how to write code in `sml`.

Comment: you and me both

Answer (score 0):

```
fun isLeaf (node(_, _, _)) = false
  | isLeaf leaf = true;

fun getMin(node(x, left, _)) =
    if isLeaf left then x
    else getMin left
  | getMin leaf = raise Empty;

fun getMax(node(x,_,right)) =
    if isLeaf right then x
    else getMax right
  | getMax leaf = raise Empty;
```

Comment: With pattern matching, your `isLeaf` function is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Think this through. A `tree` is either a `leaf` or a `node`. A `node` contains a value and two other `tree`s.

What is the maximum value of a `leaf`? It doesn't have a value, so it's `NONE`.

What's the maximum value of a `node`? Well, it's the maximum of either:

- Its value.
- The maximum value of its left branch.
- Or, the maximum value of its right branch.

How do you find the maximum value of three `int option` values? One way might be:

```
fun max(NONE,   NONE,   NONE)   = NONE
  | max(SOME a, NONE,   NONE)   = SOME a
  | max(NONE,   SOME b, NONE)   = SOME b
  | max(NONE,   NONE,   SOME c) = SOME c
  | max(SOME a, SOME b, NONE)   = if a > b then SOME a else SOME b
  | max(SOME a, NONE,   SOME c) = if a > c then SOME a else SOME c
  | max(NONE,   SOME b, SOME c) = if b > c then SOME b else SOME c
  | max(SOME a, SOME b, SOME c) = 
    if a > b andalso a > c then SOME a
    else if b > a andalso b > c then SOME b
    else SOME c
```

Answer (score 0):

More idiomatically, using more precise pattern matching, and following the `int option` specification instead of complicating things with exceptions:

```
fun getMin (node (x, leaf, _)) = SOME x
  | getMin (node (_, left, _)) = getMin left
  | getMin leaf = NONE

fun getMax (node (x, _, leaf)) = SOME x
  | getMax (node (_, _, right)) = getMax right
  | getMax leaf = NONE
```